# Selecting an image from Photo Gallery Android 4.4 with native browser get image:whatever

Tags: android, jquery, html

I made a simple application where selects a file from local storage and use jQuery prop files.

I tested on native browser in Android 4.4 and I get strange name: `image%3A12`. I don't know why.

My simple html page:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form>
   <input type="file" />
   <p></p>
</form>

<script>
$(function(){
   $(":file").on("change", function() {
      var files = $(this).prop("files");
      $("p").text(files[0].name);
   });
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

There is a bug for native browser or is a workaround to get image file name ?

One more thing, if I choose `Camera` option (instead of pick `Documents` to choose picture already saved in system), then I get correct filename with extension...

[image]

[image]

And if I select same picture (saved one), I got:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`image%3A12` is an encoded string which on decoding is `image:12`

`%3A` simply means `:` likewise '%20'means  `BlankSpace` when Encoded/Decoded

You can use the following site to check it
http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/dencoder/

Comment: I know that is encoded string, you didn't answer to my question: `There is a bug for native browser or is a workaround to get image file name ?`